# Exporting PHP Source Code to PDF with Doxygen

Tags: php, pdf, documentation, doxygen

I have a PHP project and I need to extract the whole code to a PDF. I tried to use the Doxygen, but I just return some classes or methods. I would like to have the whole code, because it is necessary for a internal process. Is there a way that I can to do it automatically?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What is missing ? Did you set `SOURCE_BROWSER`  and (un)set `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` in your doxygen configuration file? Please add some more details to your question.

Comment: It worked with your both suggestion. It was just necessary to set SOURCE_BROWSER to True and the STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS to false and now I have a new section called as a file list.